# Create sub domain using only htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain, httpd.conf

I want a way to create subdomain using htaccess or any thing to do that.

I can create subdomain with change some codes in httpd.conf, but the problem I have only a host now and I **can't edit** httpd.conf!

Comment: Are you talking about virtual hosts - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ ? That can only be configured in httpd.conf, and not in .htaccess.

Comment: You need to create a sub-domain through the interface provided by your domain registrar.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The DNS name server must resolve the subdomain to the correct IP, and Apache (or whatever HTTP server you're using) must set the correct DocumentRoot for the subdomain.

Unless those two are configured properly, the request won't get to you and the htaccess would have no effect.

Comment: Thank you (Fresh and useful answer) ^^