# Domain name customisation? htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, domain-name

I have my personal website that I am developing so I can showcase my code, photography and digital art and also blogs to the public.

Currently my site structure is :

> www.mysite.co.uk/sub-folder
>
> e.g.
>
> www.mysite.co.uk/blog

However I would like to make my site domain structure like what I have seen on some sites:

> > www.blog.mysite.co.uk
>
> or
>
> www.code.mysite.co.uk

What is this technique called?

How is it achieved? htaccess mod?

Any links or resources please could you send me them.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899805/edit-htaccess-with-php/8900619#8900619

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create sub domain using only htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085712/create-sub-domain-using-only-htaccess)

Comment: @DavidLively , thats not me. As I do not really know much about domains my question was to establish how, what and where to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.mysite.co.uk/sub-domain istn't called "Sub Domain".
Its only a sub folder.

This "blog.mysite.co.uk" are subdomains.
You must configure them in your Apache Server configuration: http://edwardawebb.com/apache/create-subdomains-apache-easy

Answer (score 0):

You can't add subdomains using htaccess. I suggest you to contact your hosting provider. Usually they give you an ability to add subdomains using their control panel.